# Rebounding Rotated BoundingSpheres

Tags: c#, xna, geometry

I'm making a 2d pinball game and using BoundingSphere for the hit box, as a short cut.

The problem I have is that a lot of things are rotating all the time and I need to work out a way to calculate a "accurate" angle of rebound when the ball hits other circular objects.

Any help, nudges and clues would be greatly appreciated

/Edit
Couldn't find anything but managed to work this out, kinda works

This is called once a collision between two BoundingSphere's is detected.

```
                private void CollisionRebound(Sprites.BaseSprite attacker, Vector2 defender)
    {
        //Work out the rotation that would result in a "dead on" collision
        //thus rebounding the attacker straight back the way they came.
        float directHitRotation = (float)Math.Atan2(defender.Y - attacker.Position.Y , defender.X - attacker.Position.X);
        //only really needed if the rotation is a negative value but is easier to work from in general.
        float attackerRotation = attacker.rotation;

        //This makes the rotation a positive number, it cant be less that -2PI
        //so adding 2PI will leave us with a positive rotation.
        if (attackerRotation < 0)
        {
            attackerRotation += (float)(Math.PI * 2);
        }


        //If the rotation is greater than the "dead on" rotation the rotation
        //needs to increase.
        if (attackerRotation > directHitRotation)
        {
            //we add "PiOver2" or "90 degrees" to "dead on" rotation because we do, dont know enough
            //trig to explain it just know it works, we then add 90 degrees minus the difference between
            //our two rotation to give us our outgoing angle, the +0.01f is for the rare case where the
            //difference is 90 which would give us no change in rotation but if the two spheres have collided
            //(which they have to before coming to this code chunk) there will be at least some change.
            attackerRotation = directHitRotation + (float)MathHelper.PiOver2 + ((float)MathHelper.PiOver2 -
                (attackerRotation - directHitRotation) + 0.01f);
        }
            //If the rotation is less than the "dead on" rotation the rotation
            //need to decrease.
        else if (attackerRotation < directHitRotation)
        {
            //same as previous chunk but we will be minusing the angle
            attackerRotation = directHitRotation - (float)MathHelper.PiOver2 - ((float)MathHelper.PiOver2 -
                (attackerRotation - directHitRotation) - 0.01f);
        }
        else if (attackerRotation == directHitRotation)
        {
            //either of the two calculations could be used here but would result in the same outcome
            //which is rotating the attacker 180 degrees, so just add 2PI instead.
            attackerRotation += (float)Math.PI;
        }

        //Here we just assign out new output rotation to the attacker entity.
        attacker.rotation = attackerRotation;
    }
```

just get the "attacker" sticking in the "defender" occasionally, any suggestions for fixing this?

added comments to explain the code for others interested in using it.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "sphere-sphere collision response". Search for that and you should find plenty of information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this, without actually trying it out, so I can't guarantee this is accurate. Also, this is pseudocode.

We need to know the collision point between the spheres. If you're waiting each frame to detect a collision then your spheres are likely going to be partially interpenetrating, so the first thing I would do is push them out of each other. In order to do that you'll need to know how far to push each one.

```
Vector3 BtoA = (SphereA.center - SphereB.center);
Vector3 AtoB = (SphereB.center - SphereA.center);

float currentDistance = AtoB.length();

float minimumDistance = SphereA.radius + SphereB.radius;

// If the spheres are interpenetrating then push them apart until 
// they're colliding only at a single point.

// Do a quick sanity check here
if ( currentDistance > minimumDistance )
{
    // Your spheres aren't close enough to be touching, how did you get here?
}
else if ( currentDistance < minimumDistance )
{
    // We move each sphere away by half of the penetration distance.
    float penetrationDistance = currentDistance - minimumDistance;

    Vector3 unitBtoA = BtoA.unitize();
    SphereA.position = SphereA.position + (unitBtoA * penetrationDistance * 0.5f);

    Vector3 unitAtoB = AtoB.unitize();
    SphereB.position = SphereB.position + (unitAtoB * penetrationDistance * 0.5f);

    // Note that now that we have repositioned the spheres they have different AtoB and
    // BtoA vectors, and theoretically could be colliding with spheres very close to
    // them that they weren't colliding with before. We now recalculate our difference vectors
    BtoA = (SphereA.center - SphereB.center);
    AtoB = (SphereB.center - SphereA.center);
}

// Ok, now we know that the spheres are only touching at one point. We can now calculate
// the reflection/deflection

// I believe the code for calculating a deflection of a velocity off of a surface
// given the normal of that surface is something like this. This assumes no energy
// is lost on the bounce as well, which isn't realistic.
Vector3 Reflect( Vector3 velocity, Vector3 surfaceNormal )
{
    const float dotProductTimesTwo = velocity.Dot(surfaceNormal) * 2.0f; 
    velocity.x -= dotProductTimesTwo * surfaceNormal.x;
    velocity.y -= dotProductTimesTwo * surfaceNormal.y;
    velocity.z -= dotProductTimesTwo * surfaceNormal.z;
}

// Using the above function, we reflect the velocities of both spheres
Vector3 unitBtoA = BtoA.unitize();
Vector3 unitAtoA = AtoA.unitize();

SphereA.velocity = Reflect( SphereA.velocity, unitBtoA );
SphereB.velocity = Reflect( SphereA.velocity, unitAtoB );
```

If you want to be more accurate with your bounce, you should be able to figure out based on the penetration depth of the spheres, how much time elapsed since they would have collided if you weren't using a frame-based application. This should allow you calculate how far apart they should be now that they've bounced off of each other. If you calculate that time then you can take the sphere's velocity that we calculated above and modify the position of the spheres by that amount of time.

```
// This variable would hold the amount of time since the spheres actually would have collided
float extra_time;

SphereA.position = SphereA.position + (SphereA.velocity * extra_time);
SphereB.position = SphereB.position + (SphereB.velocity * extra_time);
```

As I said earlier, I've not tested this code whatsoever, so it may not work at all, but at the least this may be a good starting point for you, or may be close to functional. Hopefully this helps. Good luck.